# Sort array containing objects based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript - Sort an array based on another array of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046967/javascript-sort-an-array-based-on-another-array-of-integers)
>   [Javascript - sort array based on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array)

If I have an array like this:

```
['one','four','two']
```

And another array like this:

```
[{
  key: 'one'
},{
  key: 'two'
},{
  key: 'four'
}]
```

How would I sort the second array so it’s `key` property follows the order of the first? In this case, I want:

```
[{
  key: 'one'
},{
  key: 'four'
},{
  key: 'two'
}]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Sort an array based on another array of integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046967/javascript-sort-an-array-based-on-another-array-of-integers) and/or [Javascript - sort array based on another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array?lq=1)

Comment: @TedHopp not quite, that solves two flat arrays but this cases uses object keys wich makes it more difficult to sort effectively (unless you want to search the second for each iteration).

Comment: I expected something like this to work, but somehow... it doesn't. :-/

`a2.sort(function(a,b) { a1[a2.indexOf(a)] - a1[a2.indexOf(b)] })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my take on it:

```
function orderArray(array_with_order, array_to_order) {
    var ordered_array = [], 
        len = array_to_order.length,
        len_copy = len,
        index, current;

    for (; len--;) {
        current = array_to_order[len];
        index = array_with_order.indexOf(current.key);
        ordered_array[index] = current;
    }

    //change the array
    Array.prototype.splice.apply(array_to_order, [0, len_copy].concat(ordered_array));
}
```

Sample implementation:

```
var array_with_order = ['one', 'four', 'two'],

    array_to_order = [
        {key: 'one'},
        {key: 'two'},
        {key: 'four'}
    ];

orderArray(array_with_order, array_to_order);

console.log(array_to_order); //logs [{key: 'one'}, {key: 'four'}, {key: 'two'}];
```

The usual fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/haqFH/

Comment: Using the sort function might be a better way to do it though.

Answer (score 6):

We can use the sort() function to do this by passing it a custom function which does the comparison.  This function has to return 3 possible values given `a` or `b` to compare:

`return -1` if `a` is indexed lower than `b`

`return 0` if `a` is considered equal to `b`

`return 1` if `a` is indexed greater than `b`

With this in mind, we can define a function such as this:

```
function sortFunction(a,b){
    var indexA = arr.indexOf(a['key']);
    var indexB = arr.indexOf(b['key']);
    if(indexA < indexB) {
        return -1;
    }else if(indexA > indexB) {
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;       
    }
}
```

This function will take in the objects you defined in your array, and find where that value is in the `arr` array, which is the array you're comparing to.  It then compares the index, and returns the values as needed.

We use this function by passing the function into the `sort()` function as such:

`testArray.sort(sortFunction)`

where `testArray` is the array you're trying to sort.

You can take a look at here, where I did this example, and you can see the second object in your array being "alerted" to you, before and after the sort function was called.  http://jsfiddle.net/Sqys7/

Comment: OK, but what about `arr`? I want to sort according to the `arr` order.

Comment: It is being sorted to the arr order, in the sorting function, it is taking index from `arr`, and comparing that.

Comment: Perfect , I forgot completely about the sort function , thanks for sharing :)