# how to transform or sort array against different array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const r = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'l', 'p'];

const arr = [{
        name: "ss3",
        id: 'c'
    }, {
        name: "ss2",
        id: 'b'
    }, {
        name: "ss4",
        id: 'p'
    }, {
        name: "ss1",
        id: 'a'
    }]

var newArray =arr.map((i)=>{
  let e = r[i];

  if(i.id===e){
    return i
  }
})

console.log(newArray)
```

**Expected output**

```
const arr = [{
        name: "ss1",
        id: 'a'
    }, {
        name: "ss2",
        id: 'b'
    }, {
        name: "ss3",
        id: 'c'
    }, {
        name: "ss4",
        id: 'p'
    }
]
```

Given two arrays `r` and `arr`, I wish to sort `arr` with respect to `r`, i.e. in alphabetical order by **id**.

https://jsbin.com/yitijiboso/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array containing objects based on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518343/sort-array-containing-objects-based-on-another-array)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a concise (although not very performant) way to achieve the desired output:

```js
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'l', 'p'];
const arr2 = [
    {
        name: "ss3",
        id: 'c'
    },
    {
        name: "ss2",
        id: 'b'
    }, {
        name: "ss4",
        id: 'p'
    },
    {
        name: "ss1",
        id: 'a'
    }
];

arr2.sort((a, b) => arr1.indexOf(a.id) - arr1.indexOf(b.id));
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

1. make a map from main 'arr' keyBy 'id' https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.keyby
2. loop across 'r', if key exist in new map, get value and push to new array

   ```
   const arrMap = _.keyBy(arr, 'id');
   let newR = [];
   r.forEach( key => {
      if ( arrMap[key] ) {
         newR.push( arrMap[key] );
      }
   } );
   console.log( 'new array', newR );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a clue from @Petr Broz, here's my suggestion:

```js
const r = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'l', 'p'];
const arr = [
    {
        name: "ss3",
        id: 'c'
    },
    {
        name: "ss2",
        id: 'b'
    }, {
        name: "ss4",
        id: 'p'
    },
    {
        name: "ss1",
        id: 'a'
    }
];

arr.sort((a, b) => r.indexOf(a.id) > r.indexOf(b.id));
console.log(arr);
```

Main difference is that this code utilizes the arrays as named by the OP and uses a greater than comparison operator.  However, if you just want to have the array arr sorted in alphabetical order you don't need to compare it with array r:

```js
            const arr = [
                {
                    name: "ss3",
                    id: 'c'
                },
                {
                    name: "ss2",
                    id: 'b'
                }, {
                    name: "ss4",
                    id: 'p'
                },
                {
                    name: "ss1",
                    id: 'a'
                }
            ];

           arr.sort(function(a, b) 
           {
             
             if (a.id > b.id) {
                   return 1;
             }
             else
             if (a.id < b.id) {
                    return -1;
             
             }
             else
             {
                return 0;
             } 
           });

           console.log(arr);
```

Note, in this example the return values are numeric instead of boolean values which would be helpful if the array to be sorted were to have duplicate values.

Comment: please do not use a boolean value as return value for sorting, because this approach does not return `-1` and sometimes needed. the sorting algo need longer than it has to be.