# How to sort an array of objects by key found in order of another array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following array

```
let requiredFields = ["Given Name", "Surname", "Sex", "Birth Date", "Birth Place"]
```

I am filtering an input array to only return objects where the x.key value is equal to one of the required values.

```
let filtered = fields.filter((x) => requiredFields.includes(x.key));
```

Now how do i sort this filtered array so the objects are in order of the requiredFields array.

x.key refers to a value found in requiredFields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a sorting by taking the index of the elements of `requiredFields`.

```
let requiredFields = ["Given Name", "Surname", "Sex", "Birth Date", "Birth Place"],
    filtered = fields
        .filter(({ key }) => requiredFields.includes(key))
        .sort(({ key: a }, { key: b }) =>
            requiredFields.indexOf(a) - requiredFields.indexOf(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the keys, then sort the results by the indicies found in the required fields.

```js
let fields = [
  "Age", "Birth Date", "Birth Place", "Given Name", "ID", "Sex", "Surname"
].map(field => ({ key: field }));

let filter = [ "Given Name", "Surname", "Sex", "Birth Date", "Birth Place" ];

console.log(filterSort(fields, filter));

function filterSort(data, order) {
  return orderArray(data.filter((x) => order.includes(x.key)), order);
}

// Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13518848/1762224
function orderArray(data, order) {
  return data.reduce((result, item, index) => {
    result[order.indexOf(data[index].key)] = data[index];
    return result;
  }, []);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Furthermore, you can skip the sorting by mapping the required fields to the appropriate field by its key.

```js
let fields = [
  "Age", "Birth Date", "Birth Place", "Given Name", "ID", "Sex", "Surname"
].map(field => ({ key: field }));

let filter = [ "Given Name", "Surname", "Sex", "Birth Date", "Birth Place", "Location" ];

console.log(filterSort(fields, filter));

function filterSort(data, order) {
  return order.map(o => data.find(x => x.key === o)).filter(x => x != null);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```