# Display table populated by array and ordered by another array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I found a similar post [JavaScript - Sort an array based on another array of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046967/javascript-sort-an-array-based-on-another-array-of-integers) and just need some help implementing that script with my own script.

I'm working on a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c87Jx/ which displays a table based on the array `array`'s data.

**My script:**

```
   //<![CDATA[ 
   //employee array
   window.onload = function () {

       var array = [];
       array[0] = {
           name: "John Doe",
           number: "508-555-1234"
       };
       array[1] = {
           name: "Jane Doe",
           number: "775-555-5678"
       };
       array[2] = {
           name: "Adam Doe",
           number: "603-555-9012"
       };
       array[3] = {
           name: "Karen Doe",
           number: "978-555-3456"
       };
       array[4] = {
           name: "Trish Doe",
           number: "603-555-7890"
       };
       array[5] = {
           name: "Company",
           number: "(try to reach someone)"
       };
       var arrayLength = array.length;
       var theTable = document.createElement("table");
       currentIndex = 0;
       lastIndex = array.length - 1;

       //write table header
       while (true) {
           tr = document.createElement("tr");

           td0 = document.createElement("td");
           td0.colSpan = 3;
           p = document.createElement("p");
           p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Table"));
           td0.appendChild(p);
           tr.appendChild(td0);

           theTable.appendChild(tr);
           break;
       }

       //for each employee in above array, write the attempt #, their name, and their contact info
       for (var i = 0, tr, td; i < arrayLength; i++) {

           tr = document.createElement("tr");

           td1 = document.createElement("td");
           p = document.createElement("p");
           p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Attempt #" + (array.length++-5)));
           td1.appendChild(p);
           tr.appendChild(td1);

           td2 = document.createElement("td");
           p = document.createElement("p");
           p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i].name));
           td2.appendChild(p);
           tr.appendChild(td2);

           td3 = document.createElement("td");
           p = document.createElement("p");
           p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i].number));
           td3.appendChild(p);
           tr.appendChild(td3);

           theTable.appendChild(tr);
       }
       document.getElementById("table").appendChild(theTable);
   };
   //]]>
```

**Outputs a pretty basic table like:**

```
<div id="table">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><p>Table</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p>Attempt #1</p></td>
            <td><p>John Doe</p></td>
            <td><p>508-555-1234</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p>Attempt #2</p></td>
            <td><p>Jane Doe</p></td>
            <td><p>775-555-5678</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p>Attempt #3</p></td>
            <td><p>Adam Doe</p></td>
            <td><p>603-555-9012</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p>Attempt #4</p></td>
            <td><p>Karen Doe</p></td>
            <td><p>978-555-3456</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p>Attempt #5</p></td>
            <td><p>Trish Doe</p></td>
            <td><p>603-555-7890</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p>Attempt #6</p></td>
            <td><p>Company</p></td>
            <td><p>(try to reach someone)</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Next I want to introduce a second array, which will be used to manage the order in which the data from the first array displays in the outputted table. The goal here is to be able to manipulate the *Attempt #s* without having to modify the first array.

**Example:**
The first array is written as:

## 1 - John

## 2 - Jane

## 3 - Adam

## 4 - Karen

## 5 - Trish

## 6 - Company

So I want the second array to control the first array's order, so if in the second array I wrote:

```
 var sortArr = [0,3,4,2,5,1];
```

It would make the first array output like this:

## 1 - John

## 2 - Karen

## 3 - Trish

## 4 - Adam

## 5 - Company

## 6 - Jane

As mentioned above, I found a similar post [JavaScript - Sort an array based on another array of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046967/javascript-sort-an-array-based-on-another-array-of-integers), and it seems to do exactly what I need. So my question is how do I integrate Nick's script with my current script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did:

First, I added the function created in the question you cited into your code:

```
window.onload = function () {

    function getSorted(arr, sortArr) {
        var result = [];
        // changed arr.length to sortArr.length:
        for(var i=0; i < sortArr.length; i++) {
            result[i] = arr[sortArr[i]];
        }
        return result;
    }

    //... the rest of your code
}
```

Next, I added two arrays:

```
var array = [],
    sortArr = [0,3,4,7,9,1],
    sortedArr;
```

Next, after you put all the data into the `array` variable, I called the `getSorted` function:

```
// your code putting data into array
//...
sortedArr = getSorted(array, sortArr);
```

Finally, I changed how you output data into your tables in the for loop as such:

```
// changed arrayLength to sortArr.length:
for (var i = 0, tr, td; i < sortArr.length; i++) {

    tr = document.createElement("tr");

    td1 = document.createElement("td");
    p = document.createElement("p");
    // changed (array.length++-5) to (i+1):
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Attempt #" +(i+1)));
    td1.appendChild(p);
    tr.appendChild(td1);

    td2 = document.createElement("td");
    p = document.createElement("p");
    // changed (array[i].name) to (sortedArr[i].name):
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sortedArr[i].name));
    td2.appendChild(p);
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    td3 = document.createElement("td");
    p = document.createElement("p");
    // changed (array[i].number) to (sortedArr[i].number):
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sortedArr[i].number));
    td3.appendChild(p);
    tr.appendChild(td3);

    theTable.appendChild(tr);
}
```

[Here is an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c87Jx/4/) that hopefully helps! Let me know if you have any questions!

**Edit:** I changed the number of iterations each for loop runs - both were based off `array.length`, now they are both based off of `sortArr.length`. This will only work when the length of sortArray is less than or equal to the length of array. It sounds like this will work for your situation - correct me if i'm wrong! :) Also, in the fiddle I added more data to `array` to test the new change.

Comment: Incredible answer! Thank you so much. The only question I have is, the employee array may contain more items than what actually gets outputted e.g. it might end up storing 20 employees, but the table only outputting 6. Can something be added to allow that? I see now that if the arrays don't match in quantity, the script breaks.

Comment: My understanding of what you just said is: Even if the employee array holds 20 employees (for example), you want to show only the employees that are in the `sortArr` list. Is that correct? I will work on this while I wait for your response.

Comment: I updated the code! I explained at the bottom what i did. hopefully it's to your liking