# Arrange Javascript Arrays

Tags: javascript

I have array of cars and an array of price corresponding to each car.

I want to implement the function highest3 which will return an array of 3 cars in order by their price (highest to lowest).

However, if the price is equal, then it returns the cars in alphabetical order.

In this example below, "Hummer" would be the first entry.

**Code**

```
var cars = ["Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Jaguar", "Hummer", "Toyota"];
var price = [12, 34.5, 3.54, 45.9, 3.44];

result == ["Hummer", "Lamborghini", "Ferrari"];

function highest3 (cars, price) {

//Please help me here.

}
```

Can someone please help me to implement the highest3 function? I am a newbie. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Sort an array based on another array of integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046967/javascript-sort-an-array-based-on-another-array-of-integers)

Comment: This looks a lot like homework.

Comment: Have you put in any effort?

Comment: Here is my work. Can you please help me? I can't seem to figure it out. http://jsfiddle.net/d5vTc/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for you.
First of all it creates an `array` of `objects` which represent the cars and their associated values (`joinCarPrices`).

Then we perform a sort, using the custom sorting function `priceSort` by using the [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.
Which sorts the cars based on the algorithm you asked for.
Lastly, we use [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to only have the 3 highest prices cars.

```
var cars = ["Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Jaguar", "Hummer", "Toyota"],
price = [12, 34.5, 3.54, 45.9, 3.44],
result,
joinCarPrices = function () {
    var index = 0,
        carPrices = [];

    for (index = 0; index < cars.length; index++) {
        carPrices[index] = {
            'car': cars[index],
            'price': price[index]
        };
    }

    return carPrices;
},
priceSort = function (a, b) {
    // If the first car is less than the second car
    if (a.price < b.price) {
        return 1;
    } else if (a.price > b.price) {
        // If the first car is more than the second car
        return -1
    } else {
        // Else sort by the car name
        return a.car < b.car ? -1 : 1;
    }
};

cars = joinCarPrices(); // Join the Cars/Prices together as Objects, into an array
result = cars.sort(priceSort); // Sort the Cars based on the Price Sort function
result = result.slice(0, 3); // Slice to only give us array items 0-3
console.log(result);
```

And heres a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hW7se/) showing it working!

Answer (score 1):

This is only one possible solution:

```
//I assume you get the arrays correctly linked i.e price[0] is the 
//price of cars[0]
var cars = ["Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Jaguar", "Hummer", "Toyota"];
var price = [12, 34.5, 3.54, 45.9, 3.44];

result == ["Hummer", "Lamborghini", "Ferrari"];

function highest3 (cars, price) {

//First we unite the two arrays 
carsAndPrice = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i = i +1)
    carsAndPrice[i] = {car:cars[i],price:price[i]};
}
//Now that the price and the cars are strongly linked we sort the new array
//I'm using bubble sort to sort them descending this seems to be more of 
//a beginner question
var swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var j=0; j < carsAndPrice.length-1; i++) {
            if (carsAndPrice[i].price < carsAndPrice[i+1].price) {
                var temp = carsAndPrice[i];
                carsAndPrice[i] = a[i+1];
                carsAndPrice[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
  //return the name of the first 3 cars from the array
  var result = [];
  result[0] = carsAndPrice[0].price; //Most expensive
  result[1] = carsAndPrice[1].price;
  result[2] = carsAndPrice[2].price;
  }
```